# Как поставить пробел после запятой в строке?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Нужно вставить 1 пробел
после каждой запятой, если он отсутствует перед следующим словом.
У меня есть код, но он ожидаемо не работает

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
char sentence[256];
printf("Введіть текст: ");
fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++) {
  if (sentence[i] == ',' && sentence[i++] != ' ') {
  sentence[i] = sentence[i + 1];
  sentence[i++] = ' ';
}
}
printf("\nВаш редагований текст: %s", sentence);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все символы правее сдвинуть на один вправо. И не забыть проследить, чтоб места хватало...

Comment: Выражение `i++` возвращает **старое** значение числа, которое было до прибавления

Comment: @Harry А как сдвинуть этот массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сдвинуть массив? Примерно так:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char sentence[256];
    printf("Введiть текст: ");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(sentence); i++)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == ',' && sentence[i+1] != ' ')
        {
            for(int j = strlen(sentence)+1; j > i; --j)
                sentence[j] = sentence[j-1];

            sentence[i+1] = ' ';
        }
    }
    printf("\nВаш редагований текст: %s", sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

В принципе нужна еще проверка, что места в массиве для сдвига хватит, но это уж подумайте сами...

Comment: Почему не двигаете массив с помощью `memmove`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Потому что ТС так работает; ему надо пояснить сам принцип...

Answer (score 1):

Это уже не C++, а C какой-то. Забудьте про `printf()` и `fgets()`, в C++ используют `cout` и `cin`. Используйте класс `std::string`. Почитайте это [Кляц](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82), а после уберите `i++` где оно не нужно, заменив на `i + 1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    string usrStr;
    string finStr;
    cout << "Введите текст: " << endl;
    getline(cin, usrStr);
    for (size_t x = 0; x < usrStr.length(); x++)
    {
        if (usrStr[x] == ',')
        {
            if (usrStr.length() <= x + 1)
            {
                finStr += ',';
                break;
            }
            if (usrStr[x + 1] != ' ')
            {
                finStr += ", ";
            }
            else
            {
                finStr += ',';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            finStr += usrStr[x];
        }
    }
    cout << "Ред. строка: " << finStr << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

> Ввод: I,Love, C++

> Вывод: I, Love, C++

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно сделать это именно методами C